# How to pass list in hql query where list is a value of a map

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a leaveList containing 4 leave names.This leaveList is passed as map value.I want to get leave details from CompanyLeave Table by passing leaveList in hql query.Let be considered,my Company Leave Table contains 6 leave details.leaveList has 3 leave names.I want to get details of these 3 leaves from CompanyLeave Table.

Code for Hql query here leaveNameList is a list as well as map

```
public List<CompanyLeaveType> getByValidLeave(Map<String, Object> params) {

        Query query = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from CompanyLeaveType WHERE companyCode = :companyCode and leaveName IN (:leaveNames)");                                                                  
        query.setParameter("companyCode", params.get("companyCode")); 
        query.setParameter("leaveNames", params.get("leaveNameList")); 
        List<CompanyLeaveType> validLeaveDetails = query.list();

        return validLeaveDetails;

    }
```

N.B: I have got java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String error.How can I pass list in hql query?

Answer (score 1):

Use query.setParameterList(), Check the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameterList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection%29) here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Query query = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from CompanyLeaveType WHERE companyCode = :companyCode and leaveName IN (:leaveNames)");                                                                  

        query.setParameter("leaveNames", params.get("leaveNameList"));
```

Here you are trying to add a list object to the Hql query. 
Here in this case the generated query by hibernate looks like this(actually its not happened and is just to make you to understand whats going on here)

```
1) Select *from companyLeveType_Table where companyCode=someX and leaveName in(ListObject)
```

But here the leaveName is of type java.lang.String and hence hibernte frameworks expects the values should be the string only. see the sample code (Hibernte expects this)

```
2) Select *from companyLeveType_Table where companyCode=someX and leaveName in("A","B","C");
```

from first query its obvious that hibernate framework tries to convert the java.util.ArrayList to java.lang.String and hence exception throws.

Solution 1)

```
public List<CompanyLeaveType> getByValidLeave(Map<String, Object> params) {

    Query query = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from CompanyLeaveType WHERE companyCode = :companyCode and leaveName IN (:leaveNames)");                                                                  
    query.setParameter("companyCode", params.get("companyCode")); 
    query.setParameterList("leaveNames", params.get("leaveNameList")); // changes here only remaining is same
    List<CompanyLeaveType> validLeaveDetails = query.list();

    return validLeaveDetails;

}
```

Solution 2:
   Use Criteria api.

```
 public List<CompanyLeaveType> getByValidLeave(Map<String, Object> params) {
       Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(CompanyLeaveType.class);
       criteria.addCriteria(Restrictions.eq("companyCode",params.get("companyCode")))
        .addCriteria(Restrictions.in("leaveName",params.get("leaveNameList")));

        List<CompanyLeaveType> validLeaveDetails =criteria.list();

        return validLeaveDetails;

    }
```

I hope this helps you